# How to property bind blob inside a variable containing HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Let's say I have a variable containing a string of HTML:

```
let html = '<img src="https://example.com/image.png">';
```

How can I set a property binding to the `src` attribute?

I've tried `html.replace('src', '[src]');` but I think it's treated as just text, because when I retrieve the image as a blob and use the `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` it gives me:

```
<img [src]="SafeValue must use [property]=binding: blob:file:///[GUID]">
```

So when I output the HTML on the template it's not going to work.

Comment: can you crate a plunker or just post complete code which causing problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your HTML containing the img comes from a variable and not a template you cannot use property binding for the img src. Instead use string replace to set the blob url inside img src, and then bypass security for the html variable using DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml into a property on your component called let's say sanitizedHTMLvariable. Then you can bind this property to your component template using

```
<div [innerHTML]="sanitizedHTMLvariable"></div>
```

So in this case no need to bypass security for the Blob URL, but rather on the full HTML contents in the variable (provided that you trust the HTML content).